# Software to aid writing Research Papers

Tags: windows, windows-xp, software-rec

Have been working on this white paper for weeks, and have been having a very rough time with all the links and reference material i have found online, finally got them organized but this is a very manual procedure are there any software's that:

> 1) Organize , sort and bookmark your
>   links and reference pages and give you
>   one click access to them
>
> 2) Auto generate the bibliography,
>   based on what you already linked
>
> 3) Give you templates of research
>   paper layouts
>
> 4) Templates and examples of index's

P.S: Need software for Windows XP, and it can be a paid software

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/)?

> LyX is a document processor that encourages an approach to writing based on the structure of your documents (WYSIWYM) and not simply their appearance (WYSIWYG).

If you combine it with a good bibtex frontend like [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) you have a winning duo.

---

Let's take your requests one by one:

## Organize , sort and bookmark your links and reference pages and give you one click access to them

JabRef does a wonderful job with letting you enter, categorise and organise your bibliography entries.

[image: JabRef screen]

## Auto generate the bibliography, based on what you already linked

This is a snap with Lyx. Simply include your JabRef-managed bibliography file and start quoting from it. Add a bibliography entry and it will be auto-generated.

[image: Lyx citation]

## Give you templates of research paper layouts

Lyx, being based on Latex, has a wealth of formats suitable for various journals and institutions.

## Templates and examples of indexes

Indexes are automatically managed, once you add index entries.

Comment: +1. I think the real problem is that people are brought up learning to use a piece of software that focuses on presentation when the assignment focuses on semantics.

Answer (score 5):

[Endnote](http://www.endnote.com/) is very good for this.

If you use Firefox, [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) is an extension that is also pretty good.  I used it for Chicago/Turabian papers, though at the time, it didn't have bibliography generation for it.  Check [here](http://www.zotero.org/styles) to see if yours is supported.

Comment: +1 I can recommend Endnote for your bibliography, note that you can often download/import references from the scientific search engines. But this will probably only work if the software uses standard formats

Comment: +1 for Zotero (but not Endnote...). Zotero can also import papers/metadata from scientific search engines, as they appear in Firefox. It also works well with BibTex and Lyx/LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

I believe [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) fits quite a few of your requirements.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Microsoft Onenote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/) for keeping track of all your links and snippits and screen clippings, etc?  *Highly recommend, it is awesome!*

Answer (score 0):

[Flamory](http://flamory.com) offers distraction-free bookmarking. With a single hotkey press, it saves selection, screenshot, and position within the document.

I used OneNote for a long time, but for me, the hardest part was to find the needed bookmark, after I've made hundreds of them. With Flamory things got better, because I can quickly scroll through visual thumbnails and even search by the content of bookmarked document.